# Average of numbers based on distinct count of numbers in mdx

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a query as

`select [num] on 0,
       [measure][count] on 1
from [table];`

it give me say following

[num]   -> 1 2 3
[count] -> 3 4 5

Now I want to take out average of the following, i.e ( 1*3 +  2*4 + 3*5 )/(3+4+5).

Can someone suggest a mdx query for it.

Comment: Can you add the script for the set `num` please?

Comment: WITH SET num AS {[Doc].[Time].[Time] }, Select 
num ON 0,
[Measures].[Count] ON 1
FROM [Table];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code multiples each members's value with it's count and sums it up into a new measure.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.Multiplied AS

{num}.CURRENT.ITEM(0).ITEM(0).MEMBER_VALUE * [Measure].Count

MEMBER Measures.Avrg AS

SUM({num}, Measures.Multiplied)
/
SUM({num}, [Measure].Count)


select [num] on 0,
       {[measure].[count], Measures.Avrg} on 1
from [table];
```

**UPDATE**

For a named set, the below code should work:

```
WITH set num as
{[Doc].[Time].[Time]}

MEMBER Measures.Avrg AS

SUM({num}, [Doc].[Time].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE * [Measures].[Count])
/
SUM({num}, [Measures].[Count])


select [num] on 1,
       {[Measures].[Count], Measures.Avrg} on 0
from [Table];
```

Comment: It's untested till now. Will add the AW version soon.

Comment: {num}.CURRENT.ITEM(0).ITEM(0).MEMBER_VALUE * [Measure].Count this gives an error. StrToValue({num}.CURRENT.ITEM(0).ITEM(0).MEMBER_VALUE) * [Measure].Count, didn't work either.

Comment: Ok, I have got to ask this - What is `[num]` you have used? I assumed it to be some named set.

Comment: just to add, num is a set of numbers(represented in strings). [Measure].Count, counts the occurrence of them in a specific way, i.e  "1" -> 3, "2" ->4, "3"-> 5 times.

Comment: It gave #error as an answer, i guess {num}.CURRENT.ITEM(0).ITEM(0).MEMBER_VALUE is incompatible for multiplication.

Comment: Let me check that and get back to you. As I said, I could not test it out, but the approach should more or less work.

Comment: @any - now the code should work. Please check it out.

Comment: @any Can you upvote/mark as answer too if this works?